# Can't update PostgreSQL table with psycopg2 script even after I do commit() and autocommit=True

Tags: postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I am trying to update a PostgreSQL table running on the ElephantSQL service using psycopg2 cursor.execute SQL statements from my computer (MacOS). The script believes everything has gone fine but the table is not updated. I have specified the "connection.autocommit=True"  and also included the "connection.commit()" statement right after the cursor.execute(SQL) statement.  Nothing works.  Help would be most appreciated.

Here is a code snippet:

```
# Establish Connection
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    connection.autocommit=True
except Exception as e:
    print("******Cannot connect to DB****** \n" + "error: " + str(e))
    exit()



# ---   Later on,  when trying to update the DB

if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            username_to_delete = request.form['username']
            print(" username to delete is: " + username_to_delete)
            try:
                with connection, connection.cursor() as cursor:
                        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE username='username_to_delete';")
                        connection.commit()
                        cursor.close()
            except Exception as e:
                flash("Delete operation failed, error: " + str(e)) 
                print("Delete operation failed, try again ..." + str(e))
                return render_template("delete_user.html", form=form)
            flash("User Deleted Successfully!!")
            username_to_delete = ""
            return render_template("delete_user.html", form=form)
    
        else:
            print(" Error with Delete Form validation")
            flash(" There was a problem deleting user, try again...")
        return render_template("delete_user.html", form=form)

    else:
        flash(" User Delete failed! -  form problems")  
        return render_template("delete_user.html", form=form)
```

As I mentioned,  the script reports that the user was deleted successfully but that is not the case.

As I said, I am scratching my head with this all day.  Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have tried to add the autocommit property to the connection and I also have added the connection.commit() statement after the transactions.   Somehow this is not working for me. Your help would be most appreciated.

Comment: There is a difference between the statement running successfully (what your script checks) and it deleting one or more rows. Your script is trying to delete someone called literally 'username_to_delete'

Comment: 1) There is no point using `autocommit` and `commit()`. I would not use `connection.autocommit=True` and stick to just using `commit()` on the connection. 2) What does the server log show is happening when the DELETE is attempted? 3) A DELETE will complete successfully even if does not delete something. In other words deleting a row that does not exist is not an error.  Are you sure the value you are using for `username = <some_val>` is correct? Remember case counts. 4) Are you sure the Python code is pointing at correct database or table in database?

Comment: @Richard Hutton.Thank you for your reply.  I'm puzzeld becasue when I chek the value of the variable username_to_delete it shows the proper username in the table.   The DELETE statement's WHERE clause is column='variable'. Are you saying the clause should be column=variable? This does not seem to work either. Sorry if I'm being obtuse. I'm fairly new at Python.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver. Thanks for your reply. I agree there is no point to using both autocommit and commit(). I am just making the point that I have tried both independenlty and finally together with the same result. I will stick with the commit() as you recommend.  I'm puzzeld becasue when I chek the value of the variable username_to_delete it shows the proper username in the table. I can read values ftom the table ok. It is just when I want to update it that it fails. Will check the DB Server log to find out what the DB thinks is going on.

Comment: @Richard Hutton -    Found the problem!. It was a silly mistake. My cursor.execute statement was incorrect by not passing a tupple as the second part of the statement.  This iooks crazy but it is the way it has to be.  So the statement should read: 
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=%s;", (username,))   .  The last part: (username,) was not done properly before.  Thanks to Richard Hutton and Adrian Klaver. Your input helped me get throught this,

Comment: 1) It is not crazy that is the way it is documented [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) 2) Your example does not show using a placeholder(`%s`) and made the question different from reality. That is something you need to be careful about as it leads people down the wrong path.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver. Sorry if the example code was confusing.  But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the problem had nothing to do with the DB commit() or autocommit=True.

As pointed out by the comments, I was passing the parameters required incorrectly.

The cursor.execute statement was incorrect by not passing a tupple as the second part of the statement.

```
    try:
                with connection, connection.cursor() as cursor:
                        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%s;",(id_to_delete,))
                        connection.commit()
                        cursor.close()
            except Exception as e:
                flash("Delete operation failed, error: " + str(e)) 
                print("Delete operation failed, try again ..." + str(e))
                return render_template("delete_user.html", form=form)
```

So the statement should read: cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=%s;", (username,)) . The last part: (username,) was not done properly before. Thanks to Richard Hutton and Adrian Klaver. Your input helped me get throught this.